# How can I edit the installed nominatim server data?

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I have installed a nominatim server(using http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) for reverse geocoding and now I want to edit some data into it(add/edit new addresses), how I can do that? What tools I need for that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is, how your workflow should be:

**1. Using OSM itself:**
 You can use OSM editing and the main DB to add your new data and setup an update of your nominatim instance: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Updates

**2. Using OSM offline:**
You might create OSM files using OSM editors and submit them to your instance instead of the full planet dumps.

**3. Manual patching DB:**
Sadly I don't find any details about the DB schema, but it makes use of osm2pgsql and you will get an idea if you view at the source: https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/tree/master/sql

Comment: Thanks for your time @MaM. As I understand, point 1 is for updating your nominatim instance from others providers. I will try to use the point 2.

Comment: Updating the DB is usually done with the use of diff files. I wonder if importing a simple osm file is actually possible/supported.